# PHP: confused about if else statement - same logic or wrong understanding?

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I'm really confused, because I have an if/else statement what works at a first integration in the system, but in a second case I must rewrite the function. My opinion is, that both statements has the same logic? Or isn't it?

Statement 1: works as intended in first integration of code, but not at the second integration (always the variable `ba_geschaeftszeichen` has a string lenght of zero):

```
if (
  (isset($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) && ($kostentraeger == "sozialamt")) ||
  (isset($_POST['pk_vnr']) && ($kostentraeger == "pflegekasse"))
) {
  if (isset($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) && (strlen($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) > 0)) {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = $_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen'];
  } else if (isset($_POST['pk_vnr']) && (strlen($_POST['pk_vnr']) > 0)) {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = $_POST['pk_vnr'];
  } else {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = "";
  }
} else { $ba_geschaeftszeichen = ""; }
```

Statement 2: only this code works at the second integration:

```
if (
  (isset($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) && ($kostentraeger == "sozialamt")) ||
  (isset($_POST['pk_vnr']) && ($kostentraeger == "pflegekasse"))
) {
  if (isset($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) && (strlen($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) > 0)) {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = $_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen'];
  } else {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = "";
  }
  if (isset($_POST['pk_vnr']) && (strlen($_POST['pk_vnr']) > 0)) {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = $_POST['pk_vnr'];
  } else {
    $ba_geschaeftszeichen = "";
  }
} else { $ba_geschaeftszeichen = ""; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In statement 1, you reach 
    if (isset($_POST['pk_vnr']) && (strlen($_POST['pk_vnr']) > 0))

only if

```
if (isset($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) && (strlen($_POST['ba_geschaeftszeichen']) > 0))
```

is false.

In statement 2, you reach

```
if (isset($_POST['pk_vnr']) && (strlen($_POST['pk_vnr']) > 0))
```

regardless.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Steve, now I understand the logic of the code and know where the problem is.